# How can I split one record into two and set null values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have records with the following:

```
Id    Date          MondayMorning  MondayEvening  TuesdayMorning TuesdayEvening and so on
1   2012-01-01          2               3               2              2
2   2012-01-02          2               2               2              2
```

I want split record 1 in two records because the states of mondaymorning and mondayevening are not the same. If the state is the same then do nothing.

The result that I expect:

```
Id    Date          MondayMorning  MondayEvening  TuesdayMorning  TuesdayEvening
1   2012-01-01          2               NULL          2                 2
1   2012-01-01          NULL            3             NULL              NULL
2   2012-01-02          2               2             2                 2
```

Please remember that also the other days can vary.

I already have a query but, neem some changes. See the query on
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5712).
The output you can see here is the case where it goes wrong. For TuesdayEvening and MondayEvening I am expecting 2.

The information on SQL Fiddle is:

```
Declare @t Table(Id int identity,[Date] Datetime,MondayMorning Int,MondayEvening Int,TuesdayMorning Int,TuesdayEvening Int)
Insert Into @t Select '2012-01-01',0,2,0,2

SELECT id
    ,date
    ,MondayMorning
    ,(CASE WHEN MondayEvening <> MondayMorning THEN NULL ELSE MondayEvening END) AS MondayEvening
    ,TuesdayMorning
    ,(CASE WHEN TuesdayEvening <> TuesdayMorning THEN NULL ELSE TuesdayEvening END) AS TuesdayEvening
FROM @t 

UNION ALL 

SELECT id
    ,date
    ,NULL AS MondayMorning
    ,(CASE WHEN MondayEvening = MondayMorning THEN NULL ELSE MondayEvening END) AS MondayEvening
    ,NULL AS TuesdayMorning
    ,(CASE WHEN TuesdayEvening = TuesdayMorning THEN NULL ELSE TuesdayEvening END) AS TuesdayEvening
FROM @t
WHERE --MondayMorning <> MondayEvening
--OR TuesdayMorning <> TuesdayEvening
MondayMorning <> MondayEvening
AND (MondayMorning != 0 and MondayEvening != 0)
OR TuesdayMorning <> TuesdayEvening
AND (TuesdayEvening != 0 and TuesdayMorning != 0)
```

Comment: what shall happen e.g. if MM=ME and TM<>TE and WM=WE and DM<>DE

Comment: Why do you think the alternative data structure is more desirable?  Why not do things normalized with columns ID, reference date, Day of Week, AM or PM, and value?  Generalizing that to handle even just Wednesday AM and PM is going to be an exercise in frustration and exponential (or maybe factorial) growth.  Getting to Sunday AM and PM doesn't bear thinking about.

Comment: @bummi, [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5714) to see what the expected result is. It is working, but just in case Mornings=0 and Evenings>0 it goes wrong.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, This is a existing table structure (cant change anything) and I want to insert the data in a new table.

Comment: If you're in charge of the design of the new table, normalize it.  If you're not, bad luck.  The mess is grotesque; extending it to 7 days doesn't bear thinking about.  It isn't clear why the two dates are 1 day apart but you still have Monday..Sunday records; how does the date correlate with the days represented in the other columns?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The original structure is like : BeginDate, EndDate, MondayMorning e.d. But in my target table I need a list of dates, so I turned the date range into a list of dates and now I am trying to match the list dates with the columns (mondaymornning e.d.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2008+, using `VALUES` to construct the subquery elegantly.

```
Declare @t Table(Id int identity,[Date] Datetime,MondayMorning Int,MondayEvening Int,TuesdayMorning Int,TuesdayEvening Int)
Insert Into @t Select '2012-01-01',0,2,3,2

     SELECT t.Id, t.[Date],
            Case when MondayMorning=v.state then MondayMorning end MondayMorning,
            Case when MondayEvening=v.state then MondayEvening end MondayEvening,
            Case when TuesdayMorning=v.state then TuesdayMorning end TuesdayMorning,
            Case when TuesdayEvening=v.state then TuesdayEvening end TuesdayEvening
       FROM @t t
CROSS APPLY (select distinct State
               from (values(MondayMorning),
                           (MondayEvening),
                           (TuesdayMorning),
                           (TuesdayEvening)) v(state)) v(state)
```

On SQL Server 2005, replace the `VALUES()` derived table with SELECT .. UNION ALL, e.g.

```
CROSS APPLY (select distinct State
               from (SELECT MondayMorning UNION ALL
                     SELECT MondayEvening UNION ALL
                     SELECT TuesdayMorning UNION ALL
                     SELECT TuesdayEvening) v(state)) v(state)
```

Comment: Is there also a manner to ga from the dayparts to Day? Like: Turn MondayMorning and MondayEvening to Monday?

Comment: Is that a new requirement/question? I don't infer that from your question text.

Comment: I will post this as a new question later.

Comment: Why are you using v(state) 2 times? If i have 7 days, am i need to put v(state) 7 times at the end?

Comment: If you have 7 days, you put 7 days = 14 rows into the `Values(),()` section or the `SELECT .. UNION ALL`. The inner `v(state)` is for making up a table with the 14 rows of data, aliased as "v" with a single column "state". The outer `v(state)` is the alias for the query after doing a `DISTINCT`. I've merely chosen to use the same alias and column name twice.